# slideshow pause button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-applications, jquery-cycle

This is a slideshow,and my problem is the pause button doesn't work and it doesn't pause the slideshow.It doesn't have any errors in firebug.The button changes to resume but doesn't pause the slideshow.
I will be really really thankfull for your help.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm6.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.WebForm6" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<script 
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cycle.js"></script>

 <script style="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('.slider img:gt(0)').hide();/*hides first 2th 3th pics*/
         setInterval(function () {
             $('.slider :first-child').fadeOut()
         .next('img').fadeIn()
         .end().appendTo('.slider');
         },
      3000);
     });

     $(document).ready(function ($) {

         $('#playbutton').click(function () {
             $(this).css('margin-left', '-9999px');
             $('#pausebutton').css('margin-left', 0);
         });

         $('#pausebutton').click(function () {
             $(this).css('margin-left', '-9999px');
             $('#playbutton').css('margin-left', 0);
         });

     });

     $(document).ready(function ($) {$('#playbutton').click(function() { 
    $('#mg').cycle('resume'); 
}); });

$(document).ready(function ($) {$('#pausebutton').click(function() { 
    $('#mg').cycle('pause');
});
});
 </script>



    <style type="text/css">
        .slider
        {
           position:fixed; 
            width:750px; 
            height:400px; 
            background-color:white; 
            top: 9px; left: 12px; z-index:-1; 
            background:transparent url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
        }
         .slider img {
        border-style: none;
            border-color: inherit;
            border-width: medium;
            position:fixed;

            top: 42px;
            left: 50px;
            height: 220px;
            width: 651px;
            bottom: 267px;
        }
       #pausebutton {
    left: 356px;
    margin-left:0px;
    position:absolute;
            top: 273px;
            height: 27px;
        }
#playbutton {
    left: 356px;
    margin-left:0px;
    position:absolute; top: 273px;
            height: 27px;
}

    </style>



</head>
<body >

      <div class="slider" id="mg" >
                    <img src="slider-2.jpg"  /> 
                    <img src="slider-3.jpg"  />
                    <img src="slider-4.jpg"  />       
               </div >

<a href="#" id="playbutton"><img src="play.png" alt="play button" title="Play" /></a> 

<a href="#" id="pausebutton" ><img src="pause.png" alt="pause button" title="Pause" /></a> 




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps the `cycle` function does not exist on whatever object you attempt to call it on?

Comment: It looks very much to me like `$('#mg')` is a plain old `div`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to stop the default behaviour of the `<a>` tag as clicking it will cause your page to refresh.

```
$('#pausebutton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mg').cycle('pause');
});
```

Comment: Without any JavaScript errors in the console any attempt of an answer will be shooting in the dark. You may want to post a link up for people to take a look at the example. It will help you get a complete answer.

Comment: you mean what should I do?

Comment: I mean can you post a public link up to the page in question so others can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has logic error because when firebug hasn't any errors it show your code has not any Syntax errors.try debugging your code by firebug  or check again  your code. other thing is testing your code in multiple browser most of the time java scripts code dos not work true in all browsers .